# Need help with dot notation

Tags: javascript, object

Here's an example of my object:

```
var fruit = {
    apple: {
    }
}

var apple = this.rel;
```

Will someone please tell me why this works:

```
fruit[apple]
```

and this doesn't?

```
fruit.apple
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Javascript `foo.bar` is equivalent to `foo["bar"]`, not `foo[bar]`.

Therefore, `fruit.type` will become `fruit["type"]`, but there isn't a `type:` field in the `fruit` object, so `fruit.type` returns undefined.

Comment: also, if bar = 'abc', then foo[bar] is the same as foo['abc']

Comment: So if I just do fruit.apple it works, but if I define a variable like var fruitType = "apple", why doesn't fruit.fruitType work? I can only get it to work if I do fruit[fruitType].

Comment: @jttm: `fruit.fruitType` means `fruit["fruitType"]`. Notice the quotation marks.

Comment: Is there anyway possible to use dot notation when the quotation marks are needed? Or do I just need to use brackets?

Comment: @jttm: Just use the brackets.