# JavaScript Dot Notation with Objects in Objects

Tags: javascript, syntax

I am playing around with JS at the moment, coming from Java. I did some Tutorials and need some help with the dot and bracket notation in JS.

I made something, I consider an "Object" in JS. Its called "friends". Within this object, there is another object "bill".

```
var friends = {};
 friends.bill = {
  firstName: "Bill",
  lastName: "Gates",
  number: "(206) 555-5555",
  address: ['One Microsoft Way','Redmond','WA','98052']
 };

 var search = function(name) {
 for(var prop in friends) {
  if(friends[prop].firstName === name) {
   return friends[prop];
  }
 }
};
search("Bill");
```

This is clearly working as intended. I used bracket notation in the search-function.
BUT it isnt clear to me why this version wouldnt work the same way:

```
 var search = function(name) {
 for(var prop in friends) {
  if(friends.prop.firstName === name) {
   return friends.prop;
  }
 }
```

In my understanding, bracket and dot notation are used for the same things. I did a search on stackoverflow and I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4158198/need-help-with-dot-notation) question goes the same way, but I think I do not fully understand whats the problem with all the quotation marks.

Comment: you can't use a variable with dot notation. The variable won't be evaluated. JavaScript will try to access the property prop from your abject which doesn't exist therefore the second solution is not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use the bracket notation, you put the name of the property you want to access between the brackets, the name is a string.

When you use the dot notation, you type the property name and not the string containing the property name after the dot.

Your line:

```
friends.prop
```

Is interpreted like this by JavaScript:

Look for a property named `prop` on the object `friends`, and there is no such property so you get problems.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use a variable with dot notation. The variable won't be evaluated. JavaScript will try to access the property `prop` from your object which doesn't exist therefore the second solution is not working.

Answer (score 0):

friends.firstName is equivalent to friends['firstName']

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned `friends.prop.firstName` doesn't evaluate the `prop` as variable, but as property of the `friends` object.

You *could* evaluate the string into an object, if you, for some reason, would like to use this type of a notation.

```
var search = function(name) {
  for(var prop in friends) {
    if(eval("friends."+prop+".firstName) === name) {
     return eval("friends."+prop);
    }
  }
};
```